# Ruby/Rails find record that has no association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models: Table1 and Table2. Table1 has_many Table2, Table2 belongs to Table1. How can I find a Table1 record that doesn't have associations to Table2? Something like:

```
Table1.where(table2_relations.empty?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a more real-world example. Say we have the following classes:

```rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Then you could do the following:

```rb
Order.all.select { |order| order.products.empty? }
```

I hope that helps.